# byte配列をif文で綺麗に判定する方法

Tags: java

byte配列に格納されている値がすべて0以外なら真のif文を書きたいのですがスマートに書けません。
以下が実装例ですがもっとスマートな判定方法は無いのでしょうか？
よろしくおねがいします。

```
byte[] b = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

if (b[0] != 0) {
    if(b[1] != 0) {
        if(b[2] != 0) {
            if(b[3] != 0) {
            /* 処理  */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (b[0] != 0 && b[1] != 0 && b[2] != 0 && b[3] != 0)
```

でいいのでは。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
後者のほうがスッキリしていますが前者のほうがわかりやすいので前者に致します。

Comment: 後者は質問文が提示している条件と一致していないと思います。(いずれかがゼロ以外なら `true` になる)

Comment: ご指摘通り、「後者」の解法は誤っていたので削除しました。
この提示条件に対してはビット毎の論理演算では無理でしたね。

Answer (score 1):

- [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128723/4506703)
- [Java, Simplified check if int array contains int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12020361/4506703)

に似た質問がありましたので、これらの回答が参考になるかと思います。

簡潔、という点ではライブラリを利用する方法が挙げられます。

[Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```java
// import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;

if (!Bytes.contains(b, (byte) 0)) {
    /* 処理 */
}
```

[Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

```java
// import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

if(!ArrayUtils.contains(b, (byte) 0)) {
    /* 処理 */
}
```

いずれの実装も結局配列の要素を `for` ループで確認しているだけなので、自前での実装も(汎用性が不要なら特に)簡単です:

```java
// 使い方: if (!containsZero(b)) { /* 処理 */ }

public static boolean containsZero(final byte[] array) {
    for (final byte b : array) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

スマートかは解りませんが

```
byte[] b = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
byte checker = b[0]|b[1]|b[2]|b[3];

if (ckecker == 0x00) {
    // 全ビットが0の時の処理
}
```

などはいかがでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

`contains`系を使うとうまくいきそうですが、byteだとうまくいきませんね。

```java
byte[] b = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
        
boolean contains = Arrays.asList(b).contains(0x00);

if(contains) {
  System.out.println("Hello");
} else {
  System.out.println("World");
}
```